# how to serialize for android.location class?

Tags: java, android, serialization, location, deserialization

I'm trying to serialize my location class (using android.location class)

but, it gives me an error!

```
11-21 21:25:37.337: W/System.err(3152): java.io.NotSerializableException: android.location
```

So, I tried to extend the `android.location.Location` class.

```
private class NewLocation extends Location implements Serializable {
        private String Provider;
        private double Latitude, Longitude, Altitude;

private float bear;
        public NewLocation(Location l) {
            super(l);
            Provider = l.getProvider();
            Latitude = l.getLatitude();
            Longitude = l.getLongitude();
            Altitude = l.getAltitude();
            bear = l.getBearing();
        }
    }
```

After that, i tried to serialize the extended class, but the same error.

Here is the serialization code

```
 public static byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutput oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bao);
        byte[] data = null;
        oos.writeObject(obj);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        data = bao.toByteArray();
        return data;
    }
```

why this error?

Comment: To serialize a class you need to make sure all other classes are also Serializable that your NewLocation is referencing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Android's [**`Location`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) class already **implements** `Parcelable`. So you are better off with it rather than implementing your own Serialization.

Simply use the following to get `bytes` out from `Location`:

```
Parcel p = Parcel.obtain();
objLocation.writeToParcel(p, 0);
final byte[] b = p.marshall();      //now you've got bytes
p.recycle();
```

*However, you should not save bytes (in persistent storage) from `Parecelable` object for later use because it is designed for high-performance IPC transport, and is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism.*

Comment: @ArthurMelo you need to use **unmarshall** method for the reverse process. [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18000094/966550)

Answer (score 3):

I needed to serialize `Location` with most of it's members as well, not just latitude and longitude. I ended up writing my own `Serializable` class. The source code is bellow. The usage would be:

```
SerializableLocation serializable = new SerializableLocation(fromLocation);
Location toLocation = serializable.toLocation();
```

Few notes:

1. `Location`'s extras (`Bundle`) are not serialized
2. Information is original `Location` coming from mock provider or not is lost. `Location.setIsFromMockProvider` can be called only by the system.

Here is the source code:

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class SerializableLocation implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int HAS_ALTITUDE_MASK                      = 1;
    private static final int HAS_SPEED_MASK                         = 2;
    private static final int HAS_BEARING_MASK                       = 4;
    private static final int HAS_HORIZONTAL_ACCURACY_MASK           = 8;
    private static final int HAS_MOCK_PROVIDER_MASK                 = 16;
    private static final int HAS_VERTICAL_ACCURACY_MASK             = 32;
    private static final int HAS_SPEED_ACCURACY_MASK                = 64;
    private static final int HAS_BEARING_ACCURACY_MASK              = 128;
    private static final int HAS_ELAPSED_REALTIME_UNCERTAINTY_MASK  = 256;

    private String provider;
    private long   time                             = 0;
    private long   elapsedRealtimeNanos             = 0;
    private double elapsedRealtimeUncertaintyNanos  = 0.0f;
    private double latitude                         = 0.0;
    private double longitude                        = 0.0;
    private double altitude                         = 0.0f;
    private float  speed                            = 0.0f;
    private float  bearing                          = 0.0f;
    private float  horizontalAccuracyMeters         = 0.0f;
    private float  verticalAccuracyMeters           = 0.0f;
    private float  speedAccuracyMetersPerSecond     = 0.0f;
    private float  bearingAccuracyDegrees           = 0.0f;
    private int    fieldsMask                       = 0;
//  private Bundle extras = null;

    private boolean hasElapsedRealtimeUncertaintyNanos() {
        return (fieldsMask & HAS_ELAPSED_REALTIME_UNCERTAINTY_MASK) != 0;
    }

    private boolean hasAltitude() {
        return (fieldsMask & HAS_ALTITUDE_MASK) != 0;
    }

    private boolean hasSpeed() {
        return (fieldsMask & HAS_SPEED_MASK) != 0;
    }

    private boolean hasBearing() {
        return (fieldsMask & HAS_BEARING_MASK) != 0;
    }

    private boolean hasAccuracy() {
        return (fieldsMask & HAS_HORIZONTAL_ACCURACY_MASK) != 0;
    }

    private boolean hasVerticalAccuracy() {
        return (fieldsMask & HAS_VERTICAL_ACCURACY_MASK) != 0;
    }

    private boolean hasSpeedAccuracy() {
        return (fieldsMask & HAS_SPEED_ACCURACY_MASK) != 0;
    }

    private boolean hasBearingAccuracy() {
        return (fieldsMask & HAS_BEARING_ACCURACY_MASK) != 0;
    }

    private boolean isFromMockProvider() {
        return (fieldsMask & HAS_MOCK_PROVIDER_MASK) != 0;
    }

    public SerializableLocation(@NonNull Location l) {

        provider             = l.getProvider();
        time                 = l.getTime();
        elapsedRealtimeNanos = l.getElapsedRealtimeNanos();
        latitude             = l.getLatitude();
        longitude            = l.getLongitude();

        if (l.hasAltitude()) {
            altitude = l.getAltitude();
            fieldsMask |= HAS_ALTITUDE_MASK;
        }
        if (l.hasSpeed()) {
            speed = l.getSpeed();
            fieldsMask |= HAS_SPEED_MASK;
        }
        if (l.hasBearing()) {
            bearing = l.getBearing();
            fieldsMask |= HAS_BEARING_MASK;
        }
        if (l.hasAccuracy()) {
            horizontalAccuracyMeters = l.getAccuracy();
            fieldsMask |= HAS_HORIZONTAL_ACCURACY_MASK;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            if (l.hasVerticalAccuracy()) {
                verticalAccuracyMeters = l.getVerticalAccuracyMeters();
                fieldsMask |= HAS_VERTICAL_ACCURACY_MASK;
            }
            if (l.hasSpeedAccuracy()) {
                speedAccuracyMetersPerSecond =
                    l.getSpeedAccuracyMetersPerSecond();
                fieldsMask |= HAS_SPEED_ACCURACY_MASK;
            }
            if (l.hasBearingAccuracy()) {
                bearingAccuracyDegrees = l.getBearingAccuracyDegrees();
                fieldsMask |= HAS_BEARING_ACCURACY_MASK;
            }
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

            if (l.hasElapsedRealtimeUncertaintyNanos()) {
                elapsedRealtimeUncertaintyNanos =
                    l.getElapsedRealtimeUncertaintyNanos();
                fieldsMask |= HAS_ELAPSED_REALTIME_UNCERTAINTY_MASK;
            }
        }

        if (l.isFromMockProvider()) {
            fieldsMask |= HAS_MOCK_PROVIDER_MASK;
        }
    }

    public Location toLocation() {

        Location l = new Location(provider);

        l.setTime(time);
        l.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(elapsedRealtimeNanos);
        l.setLatitude(latitude);
        l.setLongitude(longitude);

        if (hasAltitude()) {
            l.setAltitude(altitude);
        }
        if (hasSpeed()) {
            l.setSpeed(speed);
        }
        if (hasBearing()) {
            l.setBearing(bearing);
        }
        if (hasAccuracy()) {
            l.setAccuracy(horizontalAccuracyMeters);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            if (hasVerticalAccuracy()) {
                l.setVerticalAccuracyMeters(verticalAccuracyMeters);
            }
            if (hasSpeedAccuracy()) {
                l.setSpeedAccuracyMetersPerSecond(speedAccuracyMetersPerSecond);
            }
            if (hasBearingAccuracy()) {
                l.setBearingAccuracyDegrees(bearingAccuracyDegrees);
            }
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

            if (hasElapsedRealtimeUncertaintyNanos()) {
                l.setElapsedRealtimeUncertaintyNanos(
                    elapsedRealtimeUncertaintyNanos
                );
            }
        }

//        l.setIsFromMockProvider(isFromMockProvider());

        return l;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not make a non-serializable class serializable just implementing the Serializable interface.
A serializable class must inherit from a serializable class (if an inherited class) and have all its attributes serializable themselves.

*All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable.*
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

However, if you want to serialize a Parcelable class **it is still possible**, but surely it would not be a good practice.