# how to bluetooth read a android Location class?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, location, parcelable

i tried to using bluetooth, android write and read a Location. (usage android.location class)

so, i want to write a bytes, i was Parcelabled a Location class.

it's Bluetooth write and read that good condition.  (use android Api example, bluetoothchat)
but, when a read a bytes and convert to Location class,
not equal data for written.(-->BT send app data and BT received app data not equals.)

if using my BT send app this Location data (location.toString())

> Location[gps 27.47754312158226,126.799059 acc=??? t=?!? et=?!?
>   bear=138.43465]

but, i have a that error in BT received app.

```
11-22 15:54:21.350: E/Bundle(32355): readBundle: bad magic number
11-22 15:54:21.350: E/Bundle(32355): readBundle: trace = java.lang.RuntimeException
11-22 15:54:21.350: E/Bundle(32355):    at android.os.Bundle.readFromParcelInner(Bundle.java:1650)
11-22 15:54:21.350: E/Bundle(32355):    at android.os.Bundle.<init>(Bundle.java:83)
11-22 15:54:21.350: E/Bundle(32355):    at android.os.Parcel.readBundle(Parcel.java:1573)
11-22 15:54:21.350: E/Bundle(32355):    at android.os.Parcel.readBundle(Parcel.java:1558)
11-22 15:54:21.350: E/Bundle(32355):    at android.location.Location$1.createFromParcel(Location.java:713)
11-22 15:54:21.350: E/Bundle(32355):    at android.location.Location$1.createFromParcel(Location.java:698)
11-22 15:54:21.350: E/Bundle(32355):    at com.example.btrecv.RemoteFragment$BTConnHandler.handleMessage(RemoteFragment.java:223)
11-22 15:54:21.350: E/Bundle(32355):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-22 15:54:21.350: E/Bundle(32355):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-22 15:54:21.350: E/Bundle(32355):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-22 15:54:21.350: E/Bundle(32355):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 15:54:21.350: E/Bundle(32355):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-22 15:54:21.350: E/Bundle(32355):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
11-22 15:54:21.350: E/Bundle(32355):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
11-22 15:54:21.350: E/Bundle(32355):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 15:54:21.355: D/PRS(32355): **mLoc ==> Location[mProvider=gps,mTime=0,mLatitude=0.0,mLongitude=27.47754312158226,mHasAltitude=true,mAltitude=3.33597619E-315,mHasSpeed=false,mSpeed=0.0,mHasBearing=false,mBearing=0.0,mHasAccuracy=true,mAccuracy=120.21687,mExtras=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=0]**] <--this is not equal of send data.
```

my send and read method are usage api example bluetoothchat.

Location to Parcel method that. it's BT send app parts.

```
    public static void write(Object in) {
           Log.d("PRS", "in BTS.write, entered Object ==> "+in.toString());
            byte[] bytesOut = null;

             //parcelWrite
            Parcel p = Parcel.obtain();
            //location.writeToParcel(p, 0);
            ((Parcelable)in).writeToParcel(p, 0);
            p.setDataPosition(0);
            bytesOut = p.marshall();      //now you've got bytes
            p.recycle();

         // Create temporary object
         ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
 // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(bytesOut);
       }
    }
```

Parcel to Location method that. it's BT received app parts.

```
public Location ParcelToLoc(byte[] bytesIn) {
        //parcelRead
        Parcel e = Parcel.obtain();
        e.unmarshall(bytesIn, 0, msg.arg1); //msg.arg1 is bytes length?
        e.setDataPosition(0);

        //Parcel to Location
        Location mLoc = Location.CREATOR.createFromParcel(e);
   return mLoc;
}
```

i referencing [how to serialize for android.location class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121159/how-to-serialize-for-android-location-class)
Why it's give me an error? sorry, my poor english :)

Answer (score 0):

i think your parcel implementation is wrong

is Location Parcelable?

if it does why you have that static void write(Object in) ? it should be in the Location class.

here is an example of implementing parcel

[How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Comment: thanks your advise. but, i was check in parcel with marshall and unmarshall tested. but, it have a equal data. but, when send data use bluetooth, it has not equal Location data :$