# Use parcelable to store item as sharedpreferences?

Tags: java, android, storage, serializable

I have a couple objects, Location, in my app stored in an ArrayList and use parcelable to move these between activities. The code for the object looks like this:

```
public class Location implements Parcelable{

private double latitude, longitude;
private int sensors = 1;
private boolean day;
private int cloudiness;

/*
Måste ha samma ordning som writeToParcel för att kunna återskapa objektet.
 */
public Location(Parcel in){
    this.latitude = in.readDouble();
    this.longitude = in.readDouble();
    this.sensors = in.readInt();
}

public Location(double latitude, double longitude){
    super();
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public void addSensors(){
    sensors++;
}


public void addSensors(int i){
    sensors = sensors + i;
}

+ Some getters and setters.
```

Now I am in need of storing these objects more permanently. I read somewhere that I can serialize the objects and save as sharedPreferences. Do I have to implement serializeable aswell or can I do something similar with parcelable?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From [documentation of Parcel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html):

> Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As such, it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent storage: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable.

Comment: Ah! In that case I suppose I'll just have to serialize it instead.

Comment: @xsiand Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418160/store-and-retrieve-a-class-object-in-shared-preference

Answer (score 77):

Since parcelable doesn't help to place your data in persistent storage (see StenSoft's answer), you can use gson to persist your Location instead:

Saving a Location:

```
val json = Gson().toJson(location)
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("location", json).apply()
```

Retrieving a Location:

```
val json = sharedPreferences.getString("location", null)
return Gson().fromJson(json, Location::class.java)
```

In case you're still using Java, replace `val` with `String`, `Gson()` with `new Gson()`, `::class.java` with `.class` and end each line with a semicolumn.

Comment: Somehow Gson().toJson(location) is not working as expected, it is just giving back empty braces like {} while location is there.

`Saving best location Location[gps 37.343339,-122.097152 hAcc=1.7821856 et=+1m54s707ms alt=46.24608612060547 vel=0.6257401 mock] string>> {}`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Kotlin, I would take the approach of Cristan, but with some extension functions, see:

```kotlin
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Parcelable
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException

fun SharedPreferences.Editor.putParcelable(key: String, parcelable: Parcelable) {
    val json = Gson().toJson(parcelable)
    putString(key, json)
}

inline fun <reified T : Parcelable?> SharedPreferences.getParcelable(key: String, default: T): T {
    val json = getString(key, null)
    return try {
        if (json != null)
            Gson().fromJson(json, T::class.java)
        else default
    } catch (_: JsonSyntaxException) {
        default
    }
}
```

And then you could use it as follows, for storing:

```kotlin
sharedPreferences.edit {
    putParcelable("location", location)
}
```

And for reading:

```kotlin
val location = sharedPreferences.getParcelable<Location?>("location", null)
```

This is a pretty clean way of using the Cristan proposal. Hope it works for you :)

Comment: See gist: https://gist.github.com/ArnyminerZ/580ca9e9c404a172e583b922d453ca78

Answer (score 2):

Since Parcel should not be used to be stored in the Shared Preferences, an alternative could be to use the new Kotlin [Serialization](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html).

Here are two extension functions that add serializable to the Shared Preferences:

```
inline fun <reified S> SharedPreferences.getSerializable(key: String): S? {
    return getString(key, null)?.let {
        Json.decodeFromString(it) as? S
    }
}

inline fun <reified S> SharedPreferences.putSerializable(key: String, value: S) {
    val jsonString = Json.encodeToString(value)
    edit().putString(key, jsonString).apply()
}
```

which then can be used like this:

```
@Serializable
data class Location {
  val double latitude,
  val double longitude
}

val sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("mySharePrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val location = Location(1.1, 2.2)
sharedPrefs.putSerializable("location", location)
val locationFromSharedPrefs = sharedPrefs.getSerializable<Location>("location")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create class both Gson'able and Parcelable like

```
@Parcelize
data class ApiRate(
    @SerializedName("tp") val tp: Int,
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
    @SerializedName("from") val from: Int,
    @SerializedName("currMnemFrom") val currMnemFrom: String,
    @SerializedName("to") val to: Int,
    @SerializedName("currMnemTo") val currMnemTo: String,
    @SerializedName("basic") val basic: String,
    @SerializedName("buy") val buy: String,
    @SerializedName("sale") val sale: String,
    @SerializedName("deltaBuy") val deltaBuy: String,
    @SerializedName("deltaSell") val deltaSell: String
) : Parcelable
```

Possible.

Answer (score -5):

The preferred way would be to implement an [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService) probably