# Application crash libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1

Tags: java, android, signals, libc

I have next fatal error:

```
A/libc(30888): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 30897 (FinalizerDaemon)
```

I have no ideas what went wrong. Perhaps this is due to *RxJava*, *GsmTaskorService* or *Greendao 3*. My stacktrace below:

```
05-20 22:30:03.138: W/CursorWindow(30888): Window is full: requested allocation 72 bytes, free space 43 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
05-20 22:30:03.170: W/art(30888): Suspending all threads took: 16.742ms
05-20 22:30:03.188: D/greenDAO(30888): Window vs. result size: 14763/17235
05-20 22:30:03.191: I/WallpaperService(12782): engine paused
05-20 22:30:03.224: E/SurfaceFlinger(506): releasePendingBuffer failed: Unknown error -1 (1)
05-20 22:30:03.297: W/art(30888): Suspending all threads took: 7.836ms
05-20 22:30:03.311: I/art(30888): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 41803(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 25(5MB) LOS objects, 25% free, 47MB/63MB, paused 9.459ms total 93.646ms
05-20 22:30:03.317: W/art(30888): Suspending all threads took: 6.147ms
05-20 22:30:03.339: A/libc(30888): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 30897 (FinalizerDaemon)
05-20 22:30:03.339: A/libc(30888): [ 05-20 22:30:03.339   571:  571 W/         ]
05-20 22:30:03.339: A/libc(30888): debuggerd: handling request: pid=30888 uid=10351 gid=10351 tid=30897
05-20 22:30:03.356: W/debuggerd64(32433): type=1400 audit(0.0:1763): avc: denied { search } for name="com.google.android.gms" dev="sda35" ino=4898901 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-20 22:30:03.359: W/debuggerd64(32433): type=1400 audit(0.0:1764): avc: denied { search } for name="com.google.android.gms" dev="sda35" ino=4898901 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-20 22:30:03.369: W/debuggerd64(32433): type=1400 audit(0.0:1765): avc: denied { search } for name="com.google.android.gms" dev="sda35" ino=4898901 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-20 22:30:03.442: A/DEBUG(32433): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-20 22:30:03.443: A/DEBUG(32433): Build fingerprint: 'google/sailfish/sailfish:7.1.2/N2G47O/3852959:user/release-keys'
05-20 22:30:03.443: A/DEBUG(32433): Revision: '0'
05-20 22:30:03.443: A/DEBUG(32433): ABI: 'arm64'
05-20 22:30:03.443: A/DEBUG(32433): pid: 30888, tid: 30897, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> com.example <<<
05-20 22:30:03.443: A/DEBUG(32433): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8
05-20 22:30:03.443: A/DEBUG(32433):     x0   00000076770e8310  x1   0000007681879000  x2   00000076770e8310  x3   000000769c605ba0
05-20 22:30:03.443: A/DEBUG(32433):     x4   0000000000000006  x5   00001089131c1400  x6   000000769ceb79c0  x7   000000769d3ec008
05-20 22:30:03.443: A/DEBUG(32433):     x8   d09ec6fa4c3781c6  x9   0000000000000000  x10  0000000000430000  x11  0000000000000000
05-20 22:30:03.443: A/DEBUG(32433):     x12  000000769c605af0  x13  000000769d48f600  x14  000000769c605c08  x15  0000000000000000
05-20 22:30:03.443: A/DEBUG(32433):     x16  000000769c605ba0  x17  000000769ff8ed48  x18  0000000071ac1bdc  x19  0000000000000000
05-20 22:30:03.443: A/DEBUG(32433):     x20  00000076770e8310  x21  00000076770e8310  x22  00000000139c7128  x23  00000000139ffae0
05-20 22:30:03.443: A/DEBUG(32433):     x24  0000000000000ff8  x25  00000000139c7128  x26  000000769c605ba0  x27  d09ec6fa4c3781c6
05-20 22:30:03.443: A/DEBUG(32433):     x28  000000769d3fe000  x29  000000769c605b90  x30  000000769ceb7a20
05-20 22:30:03.443: A/DEBUG(32433):     sp   000000769c605980  pc   000000769d327604  pstate 0000000020000000
05-20 22:30:03.660: W/ctxmgr(13411): [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-1234767485#, com.google.android.gms(10019):UserLocationProducer, vrsn=10298000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null). Was: 2 for 1, account#-1234767485#
05-20 22:30:03.823: A/DEBUG(32433): backtrace:
05-20 22:30:03.823: A/DEBUG(32433):     #00 pc 000000000054b604  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickResolutionTrampoline+68)
05-20 22:30:03.823: A/DEBUG(32433):     #01 pc 00000000000dba1c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_resolution_trampoline+92)
05-20 22:30:03.823: A/DEBUG(32433):     #02 pc 00000000000f1570  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so
05-20 22:30:03.823: A/DEBUG(32433):     #03 pc 0000000001f37364  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1691000) (android.os.Parcel.nativeDestroy+128)
05-20 22:30:03.823: A/DEBUG(32433):     #04 pc 0000000001f36750  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1691000) (android.os.Parcel.destroy+76)
05-20 22:30:03.823: A/DEBUG(32433):     #05 pc 0000000001f3b2bc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1691000) (android.os.Parcel.finalize+40)
05-20 22:30:03.823: A/DEBUG(32433):     #06 pc 000000000068afe0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (offset 0x4a0000) (java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize+140)
05-20 22:30:03.823: A/DEBUG(32433):     #07 pc 000000000068b2bc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (offset 0x4a0000) (java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run+520)
05-20 22:30:03.823: A/DEBUG(32433):     #08 pc 00000000006064a4  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 0x54d000) (java.lang.Thread.run+64)
05-20 22:30:03.823: A/DEBUG(32433):     #09 pc 00000000000d25b4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+580)
05-20 22:30:03.823: A/DEBUG(32433):     #10 pc 00000000000df280  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+204)
05-20 22:30:03.823: A/DEBUG(32433):     #11 pc 000000000042a6e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+108)
05-20 22:30:03.823: A/DEBUG(32433):     #12 pc 000000000042b9e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+372)
05-20 22:30:03.823: A/DEBUG(32433):     #13 pc 000000000044b184  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+1100)
05-20 22:30:03.823: A/DEBUG(32433):     #14 pc 0000000000067f90  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+196)
05-20 22:30:03.823: A/DEBUG(32433):     #15 pc 000000000001d980  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
05-20 22:30:03.903: W/debuggerd64(32433): type=1400 audit(0.0:1766): avc: denied { search } for name="com.google.android.gms" dev="sda35" ino=4898901 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
05-20 22:30:04.695: W/ctxmgr(13411): [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-1234767485#, com.google.android.gms(10019):UserLocationProducer, vrsn=10298000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null). Was: 2 for 1, account#-1234767485#
05-20 22:30:05.762: W/ctxmgr(13411): [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-1234767485#, com.google.android.gms(10019):UserLocationProducer, vrsn=10298000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null). Was: 2 for 1, account#-1234767485#
05-20 22:30:05.801: I/art(12472): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 24297(1224KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 22MB/33MB, paused 1.281ms total 127.251ms
05-20 22:30:05.962: W/ActivityManager(12472):   Force finishing activity com.example.dev/com.example.example.ui.activities.JustActivity
05-20 22:30:05.962: W/ActivityManager(12472): [ 05-20 22:30:05.970   571:  571 W/         ]
05-20 22:30:05.962: W/ActivityManager(12472): debuggerd: resuming target 30888
05-20 22:30:05.974: I/BootReceiver(12472): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_01 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
05-20 22:30:05.984: W/ActivityManager(12472):   Force finishing activity com.example.dev/com.example.example.ui.activities.JustActivity
05-20 22:30:05.985: W/ActivityManager(12472): Duplicate finish request for ActivityRecord{41782a8 u0 com.example.dev/com.example.example.ui.activities.JustActivity t6064 f}
05-20 22:30:06.007: I/Zygote(12230): Process 30888 exited due to signal (11)
05-20 22:30:06.014: W/InputDispatcher(12472): channel '4b310aa com.example.dev/com.example.example.ui.activities.JustActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
05-20 22:30:06.015: E/InputDispatcher(12472): channel '4b310aa com.example.dev/com.example.example.ui.activities.JustActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-20 22:30:06.056: I/OpenGLRenderer(12472): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-20 22:30:06.056: D/OpenGLRenderer(12472): Swap behavior 1
```

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have same crash...

Comment: @Klemenko Did any one figure this out?

Comment: @Varun in my case it was upade in google play services and their fused location. I was serializing Location object from fused location services with gson and then saving in SharedPrefs. Deserialization back to object with gson I got this error. They somehow add something new in Location object, if I remember correctly it was Bundle object, which deserialization cause that error. Strange thing indeed but I solve this with normalizing object so only latitude and longitude got saved into SharedPrefs. If your app was working ok and suddenly you got this error it's something with 3th party app 100%

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed same error in way like @klemenko described.

Code that has caused the crash:

```
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(App.getInstance())
            .edit()
            .putLong(KEY_LOCATION_LAST_POINT_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis())
            .putString(KEY_LOCATION_LAST_POINT_PLACE, new Gson().toJson(location))
            .apply();

    ...
    SharedPreferences shp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    if (shp.contains(KEY_LOCATION_LAST_POINT_TIME)
            && (System.currentTimeMillis() - shp.getLong(KEY_LOCATION_LAST_POINT_TIME, 0)) < LOCATION_EXPIRATION_TIME_MS) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(shp.getString(KEY_LOCATION_LAST_POINT_PLACE, null), Location.class);
    }
```

So guys, don't use Gson serialization for google's Location object