# Getting Lat and Long values from FusedLocationProviderClient android

Tags: android, location

I am trying to use `FusedLocationProviderClient` to get the Latitude and Longitude of the current location.  My code so far is as follows:

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Layout: have a button

build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

Java

```
ArrayList<String> Coord_Array;
```

Inside OnCreate method

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient client;
client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient( ShowOutletParams.this );
Coord_Array = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Outside OnCreate method  - I am using `getLocation()` inside the button onclicklistener

```
private String getLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( ShowOutletParams.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( ShowOutletParams.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener( ShowOutletParams.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    String locat = location.toString();
                    String lat = locat.substring(15,24);
                    String longi = locat.substring(25,34);
                    Coord_Array.add(lat);
                    Coord_Array.add(longi);
                    //return Coord_Array;
                }
            }
        } );

    }
```

When I add `Log.i` to log the lat and long values, I could see them in the log, however I want them to be saved as strings, which I want to use later.
I understand `void` does not return anything....however the `Coord_Array` too doesn't return or print the lat and long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try :

```
client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener( ShowOutletParams.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        double mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                        double mLongitude = location.getLongitude();                           
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }}
```

if still facing issue check for the [tutorial](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/get-current-location-using-fusedlocationproviderclient-in-android-cb7ebf5ab88e)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is your method `private String getLocation()` returns before any Location is actually available (and I'm pretty sure it won't compile by looking at it).

When you're here:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( ShowOutletParams.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( ShowOutletParams.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   return;
}
```

you're still in the standard flow of your method. But once you get passed here:

```
client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(
```

all of the code within your `public void onSuccess(Location location)` is now running *AFTER* your call to `getLocation()` has already returned!

A simple solution is to pass in callbacks into your `getLocation()` method, so that they can be triggered *after* the method has already returned to its caller, e.g.

```
public interface LocationAvailableListener {
    public void onLocationAvailable(Location location)
}

public void getLocation(LocationAvailableListener locationAvaialbleCallback, Runnable locationNotAvailableCallback) {
...
```

Then when checking permissions, you can now trigger your failure callback:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( ShowOutletParams.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( ShowOutletParams.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   locationNotAvailableCallback.run();

   return;
}
```

and then in your `onSuccess`

```
if (location != null) {
   locationAvaialbleCallback.onLocationAvailable(location);
}
else {
   locationNotAvailableCallback.run();
}
```

And then to use:

```
getLocation(
   location -> {
      String latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
      String longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

      // Add to your ArrayList here
      // Save to your database or wherever for later
   },
   { Log.i(TAG, "Failed to get Location"); })
```

And since you asked about persisting the Location data once you have it, [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40379377/1426565) should point you in the right direction with some simple JSON serialization.

Comment: Thank you....This is my first app....and have never built anything with Java....will try your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for all the explanation....I clearly understand where I was going wrong....

Answer (score 0):

You have to get Longitude and Latitude directly from the location object and cast it to string as you want.

in Kotlin :

`lat = location.latitude.toString()`

and in Java :

`lat = location.getLatitude() + "";`