# Arraylist of location objects to bytes

Tags: java, android, serialization, location

Apologies if any of the terminologies i've used is incorrect, i'm currently doing an online learning course and still very new to java/Android development.

I'm trying to write a location recorder app that will save your route to a file. I've got an ArrayList of Location objects however I am unsure on how I can save the contents to to a file on the device

I've tried to serialise the Location objects however I get an '''java.io.NotSerializableException: android.location.Location''' error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am just importing the Location class using 'import android.location.Location;'

Comment: I think I'm a little out of my depth at the moment. Within my MainActivity.Java I import Location so I can use it. I dont have a public class like you mention.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Location already implements `Parcelable` and you can find more information on how to serialize it in the answers to this question: [how to serialize for android.location class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121159/how-to-serialize-for-android-location-class)